# JsonHttpContent with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I created a custom HttpContent to efficiently send objects using System.Text.Json with HttpClient. Sadly there's very little documentation around how to correctly do this. The following class results in an error about malformed JSON data at my test endpoint. Looking at the packets in wireshark shows that only an empty json object (`{}`) is transmitted. I also tried to flush the stream (same result) or dispose it after writing to it (this results in an error about tring to access a disposed object).

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Common
{
    public sealed class JsonContent : HttpContent
    {
        private readonly object _content;
        private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;

        public JsonContent(object content, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            _content = content;
            _options = options;
            Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
            {
                CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName
            };
        }

        protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, _content, _options);
        }

        protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
        {
            length = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The whole thing is used like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string url, T content,
    CancellationToken ct = default) where T : class
{
    return await client.PostAsync(url, new JsonContent(content, Json.DefaultSerializerOptions), ct);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can check this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1754#issuecomment-580729844

Comment: @Fei Thanks, but I'm using a StreamContent with a memory stream for now which works fine and is definitely more efficient than round tripping via string. But that still causes an additional copy in memory which isn't great for large objects (still better as a utf8 byte array than as a string, but unnecessary)

Comment: did you compare your implementation to a base one like one given below
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/StringContent.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly, you have missed the type of `_content`. Try this:

```
protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
{
    return JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, _content, _content.GetType(), _options);
}
```

The method you called was actually `SerializeAsync<TValue>(...)`, which uses `typeof(TValue)` as the type to serialize. Because your `_content` is an instance of `object`, so `TValue` in this case is `object`, thus `_content` was serialized as `object`. That is why you see only `{}`.

The fix calls another overload `SerializeAsync(...)` which allows you to specify the correct type to serialize.

Comment: Interesting. System.Text.Json handles this differently depending on which method is used. `JsonSerializer.Serialize(elem)` has the same behavior as Newtonsoft (use dynamic type if the static type is object). But `JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, elem)` does *not*. 
Instead of going with `GetType` which has the downside of requiring separate handling for null, I just added a generic type to the class.
Good catch.

Comment: Man, you save my day: `var postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) {Content = JsonContent.Create(parms, parms.GetType()) };`

Answer (score -1):

Does your object contain fields or properties.. System.Text.Json will not serialize fields..